# ActiveX component for SMTP proxy

Tags: vb6, activex, smtp

I'm looking for an ActiveX component which works as proxy and allows reading/manipulating SMTP traffic.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [WebMail Objects](http://www.distinct.com/products/mail-objects/wmo.asp) they're implemented as an ActiveX component. I've never used it but it looks like it may be what you are looking for.